# Converting XML to JSON with Sibling ordering (Schematron for JSON)

Tags: xml, json, xsd, schematron

I have an information system to which we can pose queries in XML like this:

```
<Query>
<Condition>
...
</Condition>
<LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
<Condition>
...
</Condition>
<LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
<Condition>
...
</Condition>
</Query>
```

This sibling order is imporant and enforced by schematron (LogicalOperator between Condition).

How can I represent this data in JSON, preserving its semantic? The JSON becomes something like

```
"Query": {
    "Condition": [{...},{...},{...}]  ,
    "LogicalOperator": ["AND","AND"]
}
```

And a lot of semantic information is lost. How can I encode all this information in JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Query": [{...},"AND",{...},"AND",{...}]
```

Deserialize with gson using the [mixed-type-collection recipe](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types)  and serialize with jaxb